# not able to send email with email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

```
  $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->loadDefault('test_template');                                    


$emailTemplateVariables = array();
 $emailTemplateVariables['test'] = 'Branko';
 $emailTemplateVariables['name'] = 'Ajzele';
 $emailTemplateVariables['reviewurl'] = Mage::getUrl('test/index/review');

echo $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

$emailTemplate->send('test@gmail.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables);
```

output `echo`

```
It is time to review Branko

Hi Ajzele

Click this Make a Review


error


2015-06-17T10:17:10+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /var/www/servicecenters/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php:40
```

Comment: Is template id correct? I doubt your template id is not getting called.

Comment: It is time to review Branko

Hi Ajzele

Click this Make a Review     this is template out

Comment: hi Qaisar, How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @mujas  just adding the store id `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()` in last parameter `$emailTemplate->send('test@gmail.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables,Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());`

Comment: Thanks you.not working,i also using the same way you used.Do i want to config anything from the back end.Accepted solution also checked in my testing server.

Comment: @mujas try with `$storeId=null` `$emailTemplate->send('test@gmail.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);` it is working code if it is not working then share you code and check your other email are working too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

So the problem was: `!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')` which you can fix up in `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings` and change `Disable Email Communications` to `No` so the emails are **NOT** disabled.

**Explanation**

Look at the `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`.The code throwing this error is:

```
if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
    Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
    return false;
}
```

Look at `isValidForSend()`:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

[More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393220/magento-not-sending-out-any-mails-how-to-debug#answer-10810193)

Comment: A little error: the correct path is Admin > System > Configuration > System > Mail Sending Settings (no > Advanced)

Answer (score 3):

For me the Problem was, that I defined a custom email template via **config.xml** of my own module and forgot to set the comment block with subject and so on.

```
<!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"htmlescape var=$customer.password":"Customer Password"}
@-->

<!--@styles
@-->
```

Comment: It was the same for me. I just added `<!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->` on top of my file "/app/locale/es_ES/template/email/sales_new_recurring.html"